# Auto Hot Key: Strange behavior on ControlClick after Gui Submit

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script that sends ControlClick + ControlSend to a window in background (while I'm working in another window). It works ok as expected.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

$F1::
sleep 1000

ControlClick, x400 y470, Notepad
ControlSend,, text, Notepad

return
```

The problem is: when I add a Gui on the script, the ControlClick behavior becomes odd once I close the Gui (with Submit or Destroy): If I'm working in a window A (Chrome for example) the ControlClick don't work in background anymore: it activates the window B (Notepad) like in the WinActivate command instead.

Here's the script with the issue (same as the previous one but with a simple Gui):

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2

Gui, Add, Text,, box
Gui, Add, Button, default, OK
Gui, Show, W300 H300
return

GuiClose:
ButtonOK:
Gui, Submit
return


$F1::
sleep 1000

ControlClick, x400 y470, Notepad
ControlSend,, text, Notepad

return
```

I'm on Windows Vista 32 bits, Autohotkey v1.1.25.01

I can't understand why the Gui Submit is changing the ControlClick bahavior. How can I fix this and let the ControlClick run in background just like it was without the Gui Submit/Destroy?

ps: both windows were maximized.

Comment: That's really odd. Are there any other scripts running in the background? Also, take a look at the reliablility section in the ControlClick documentation,  there are some things you can try: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability Do you have access to a computer with a different version of windows on which you could try your script?

Comment: Hey @Forivin "Specify the string NA anywhere in the sixth parameter" did the trick for me, thank you very much! If you post it as an aswer would be a pleasure for me to mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControlClick is known to not be very reliable in certain cases. Take a look at the [Reliability section in the `ControlClick` documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability), there are some things you can try:

> To improve reliability -- especially during times when the user is
>   physically moving the mouse during the ControlClick -- one or both of
>   the following may help:
>
> 1. Use `SetControlDelay -1` prior to ControlClick. This avoids holding
>      the mouse button down during the click, which in turn reduces
>      interference from the user's physical movement of the mouse.
> 2. Specify the string NA anywhere in the sixth parameter (Options) as
>      shown below:
>
>    ```
>    SetControlDelay -1  
>    ControlClick, Toolbar321, WinTitle,,,, NA
>    ```
>
> NA avoids marking the target window as active and avoids
>   merging its input processing with that of the script, which may
>   prevent physical movement of the mouse from interfering (but usually
>   only when the target window is not active). However, this method might
>   not work for all types of windows and controls.